# How to pass parameters to an ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a javascript class called MyTest.js, now I register this script on the load of my MyWebPage.cs, But i need to pass 3 parameters to the function which it will then make a call to a web service. Here is my javascript function

```
MyTest.init = function() {
    var params = new Hash();
    params.set("blank", "blank");
    new Ajax.Request('/Test.asmx/CreateClients', {
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: attachCallback(this, "Yay"),
        onFailure: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        onException: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        parameters: params
    });
}
```

Now the parameters i need to pass are two stings, name and notes which I can get in the load of my .cs file. How can I pass the values to this init function?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the data property:

```
MyTest.init = function() {
    var params = new Hash();
    params.set("blank", "blank");
    new Ajax.Request('/Test.asmx/CreateClients', {
        method: 'post',
        data: {Name:"name", Notes:"Notes"},
        onSuccess: attachCallback(this, "Yay"),
        onFailure: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        onException: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        parameters: params
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I later consume those parameters on C#?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using Prototype, not jQuery, but I'm not certain. If you are, you just need to populate your Ajax.Request's `parameters` object with your name and note properties.

```
MyTest.init = function(name, note) {
    var params = new Hash();
    params.set("blank", "blank");
    params.set("name", name);
    params.set("note", note);
    new Ajax.Request('/Test.asmx/CreateClients', {
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: attachCallback(this, "Yay"),
        onFailure: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        onException: attachCallback(this, "Nay"),
        parameters: params
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try, on the server side writing out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var param1 = '<%= dotNetValue %>';
 var param2 = '<%= otherDotNetValue %>';
</script>
```

then on the client you'll have access to those (global) variables

```
params.Set("first", param1);
params.Set("second", param2);
```